# Get list of images in web using shell script

Tags: linux, image, bash, shell

is there a possibility to get all images, or better image list from web (i would type it as variable) using shell script?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you've already done `man man`

Comment: What does "in web" even mean?

Comment: @Steve-o - looks like a crawler feature, `wget` more appropriate

Comment: All the images? In the whole world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://www.krazyworks.com/wget-google-image-collector/).  It fetches images from Google search given a keyword.  Should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Use curl to get html source from web site, and parse it for  tag, after that, download them all with wget or curl.