# Automating JPEG download

Tags: python

I need to download jpeg images of size > MIN_SIZE from the pages 1 <= PAGE_NUMBER <= NUM_OF_PAGES

http://somewebsite.com/showthread.php?t=12345&page=PAGE_NUMBER

How can I do that in python? I am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in Python:

- Fetch each page you need to grab image from (easy, just use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or some other HTTP fetcher library)
- Parse each HTML file to grab the image URLs.  This a bit more involved -- have a look at [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html).  From memory, you can subclass `HTMLParser` to only grab the text that you're interested in.  In this case, this is the `src` attribute from the HTML `img` tag, e.g. something like `<img src="this is what you want" width=640 height=480/>`
- Fetch each image obtained above (easy)

Personally, though, I wouldn't use Python for this.  The first and last steps of the above approach are easily done with `wget`.  The second can be performed with `grep`, with `bash` to tie everything together.  In fact, this is pretty much exactly what I recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198917/get-list-of-images-in-web-using-shell-script/4201029#4201029).

That is, of course, if you're on Linux.  If you don't have bash and get Python may be your next best option.